# Subdomains. How do you do development with subdomains?

Tags: ip, subdomain, cname, hosts

I am currently building an web app which also utilizes websockets. (Rails for webserver and Nodejs for socket.io)

I have structured my application to use subdomains to separate between connection to the Nodejs server and the Rails webserver. I have "socket.mysite.com" redirected to the Node server and everything else to the webserver.

I am able to test this functionality on localhost. I simply modified my /etc/hosts to include the following:

```
127.0.0.1 socket.mysite.com
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
```

I know that on production I simply have to generate a CNAME record for socket.mysite.com and this will also work on my users' computers.

However, I am accustomed to testing my application by passing an IP address around. My team typically set up the server on our own machines and do development. When we want to test our individual servers, we just pass around an IP like "http://123.45.123.45".

With the new subdomain hack, this is no longer possible without modifying each of my tester's /etc/hosts. I honestly don't expect my testers to modify their /etc/hosts on the spot. What I can do is have each member of my team have their own domain and create the appropriate CNAME records for each individual team member.

Is there an easier way to allow me to run my app on an IP and just pass that IP around?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your needs have scaled beyond the days of just simply editing a host file. While you could continue to have everyone on your team continue to edit host files, there are two main risks that I see here:

- For your idea to just use IP Addresses, you risk missing something in testing that you wouldn't see unless you were on production, as the issue may be dependent on something in the domain configuration.
- For using host entries, you introduce a lot of complexity and unnecessary changes to each developer and tester's configuration, which of course leaves the door open for mistakes, and it also takes time that will add-up over the long term.

Setting up a DNS server may be helpful in your case. You could map a set of domains for each developer that match a certain pattern so that your application will still run correctly. This would allow you to share the URLS without having to constantly reconfigure each person's computer. Additionally, marketing and sales stakeholders can easily view product demos as well, without needing to learn what the elusive host file is for.

If you have an IT department, they can help you setup the DNS. However, if you are a small team without a real IT department, some users have found success using [DNS systems designed for home or small office networks](http://mark.koli.ch/2010/03/howto-setting-up-your-own-local-dns-server.html).

Comment: I am currently a two person team working out of my living room. Do you have anything quicker and easier to recommend?

Comment: You may want to *search* on [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). You're more likely to find more targeted results there.